# Unable to Properly Push to a Queue within an fscanf() Loop

Tags: c, queue, scanf

I'm trying to create code where I can parse through a file while pushing it's contained hostnames as strings onto a queue, however I'm running into some major problems.  My code's below:

```
while(fscanf(inputfp, "%1024s", hostname) > 0){
    i++;
    queue_push(&q, hostname);
    printf("%s\n", hostname);
    printf("%d\n", i);

}
```

After I've run this code, while I try popping the queue to see what's inside, It's populated entirely by duplicates of the last hostname in my file, even though the queue has the right number of elements in it.

I assume that the problem lies somewhere in the looping of the fscanf function, as the queue works perfectly outside of this provided while loop.

I've also tried debugging this, only to find even more strange behavior.  For instance, if I try and push the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd hostnames from my file and the pop the queue twice, the 5th and 6th hostnames are popped instead of the 1st and 2nd.

Also, if I run through this while loop simply printing the hostnames, the output is exactly as I would expect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What those who are struggling with debugging assume is wrong in many case. Please show the implementation of queue.

Comment: What is the size of `hostname`? `scanf("%1024s", hostname)` implies `hostname` is at least 1025 bytes long.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what `queue_push` does, but if it just puts the object you're passing onto the queue, you're pushing the same pointer every time (the address of your `hostname` buffer). You probably need to make a copy of hostname (you can use `strdup()` for that). Just make sure to free those allocated strings when you're done with them.